# How to add the last X blogs on a page other than the home page?

Tags: drupal, web, blogs

I just started a drupal blog, found [here](http://www.simplykyra.com/) but extremely rudimentary, and I want to display the last X blogs on pages other than the homepage.

Basically for the drupal site I downloaded the ability to add blog posts. Right now when I got the site's homepage it shows the last 5 blogs that were added (I know where to change the number of blogs shown). Currently I have added a story (or can change to page) to the navigation bar for each of my subjects for my blogs. For example the `Food` heading on the navigation will have all the food-related blogs added to that menu. I want it so when the user clicks on `Food` it displays the last X number of Food-blogs. So basically I want it to have the same behavior as the homepage with the ability to display a different number than the homepage and to choose from a smaller number of specific blogs.

Is there a way that I can easily do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, is to use the [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module. With it you can create a listing of the X resent blog posts, and make a block out if it. This block you can display in any of your theme regions, like you would with any Drupal block.